# Caesar Cipher Going back to 'A'/'a'

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void encrypt(char *theString, int shift) {
    while (*theString) {
        if (isalpha(*theString)) {
            *theString += shift;
        }
        theString++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int shift;
    int *ip;

    ip = &shift;
    char theString[80];
    printf("Enter String: ");
    fgets(theString, 80, stdin);
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    encrypt(theString,shift);
    puts(theString);

    return(0);
}
```

Got this far, thanks for the help.

Now, I need help going back to 'A' when the user types 'Z', instead of going to [ (and for lowercase letters).  I know I need some if statements, not sure which ones. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You'll have to check the ascii value after the shift, its its greater than 'Z', then subtract 26 and you'll loop back around. Decrypting will simply be the opposite. I'm also assuming the shift amount will never be greater than 26 for this

Comment: Your indentation makes me sad.

Comment: @Kay Can't have an increase in indentation caused world sadness.  Reformatted for your pleasure!

Comment: @EdwinBuck, thank you! It's like an early Christmas present. :D

Comment: `*theString = (*theString - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A';` so you do operation `mod 26` (26 is not magic, but the number of letters in the alphabet)

Comment: So I tried using the - 26 code and the one directly above, but I keep getting the same error. Whenever I type string "zzzz" I get "????" as a result. All the other letters work, and when I type "ZZZZ" I get the correct output. The code is exactly the same for both upper and lower, so what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

First rotate the character.  This might lead to invalid characters (rotating past Z).

After rotating the character, check the character to see if it is greater than 'Z'.  If it is, then you need to figure out how far past 'Z' it is.  To do this, subtract 'Z' from the character.

You now have "how far past Z" the character is.  You need to take this number and convert it to "how far past A", which means you would subtract 1.

Now that you have "how far past A", you can just add the character 'A' to the value, and you will get the desired value.

To summarize, "subtract off 'Z', add 'A' and subtract 1".

```
while (*theString) {
    if (isalpha(*theString) && isLower(*theString)) {
        *theString += shift;
        while (*theString > 'z') {
            *theString = *theString - 'z' - 1 + 'a';
        }
    } else if (isalpha(*theString) && isUpper(*theString)) {
        *theString += shift;
        while (*theString > 'Z') {
            *theString = *theString - 'Z' - 1 + 'A';
        }
    }
    theString++;
}
```

Comment: "subtract off 'Z' add 'A' and subtract 1", or simply subtract 26. I think we can take the number of letters in the ASCII alphabet as a well known constant. :)

Comment: @Kay Always nice to avoid magic numbers, even when they work :)

Comment: That is not a method that conform with the C standard.  The C standard only requires the digits `'0'`-`'9'` to be represented consecutively.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, but the C standard doesn't require any particular character set, so it is both impossible to "conform to the C standard" and impossible to "violate the C standard" with regard to character manipulation.  EBCDIC is the only character set that comes to mind where the alphabet is not continuous, and the only sane way to do it there is a lookup table.